# Mouse location over zone with position:absolute divs covering zone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of `float:left` divs with a variety of `position:absolute` divs overlayed. On mouse over left or right 1/4 of the whole I require the respective previous/next button to appear. The following example hopefully shows the dilemma. Std. mouseover (rem'd) does not work if coming in over the 2nd div.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<div id="x" style="background: transparent; width:222px; height:222px; border:1px solid red">  
  <BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>TheZone
</div>  

<div id="y" style="background: #EDEDED; width:112px; height:113px; position:absolute; top:-12px">  
  <BR><BR><BR>Cover the zone
</div>  

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // $('#x').mouseover(function() { alert('in'); });
      $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
          if (e.pageX > $('#x').offset().left && e.pageX < $('#x').offset().left + $('#x').width() && e.pageY > $('#x').offset().top && e.pageY < $('#x').offset().top + $('#x').height()) {
              alert('zoned');
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

The pageX/Y solution works but I wonder if there is a simpler, more elegant, solution. Especially as the equivalent mouseout - a reversed repeat of the 'in zone' code with || ... and a triggered variable so the outside-the-zone condition isn't constantly looping - really looks to me like a patchy work-around. Any alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly but couldn't you just attach the event handler the both the underlying `div` and the on positioned over it?

http://jsfiddle.net/o7pzb7je/

Alternatively, if you could restructure your HTML so the absolutely positioned `div` (`#y`) is positioned within the larger one (`#x`), you can attach the event handler to the outer `div` (`#x`) as normal.

http://jsfiddle.net/6mnLfLu1/

Comment: yes, except the overlays commonly extend outside the trigger zone. Also the overlays have a separate mouse event and, generally I would like to limit the triggering of the prev/next buttons.

Comment: @Arfa - So the overlays already have a mouse event, and you want the underlying div to trigger an event when an overlay which is over the underlying div is hovered? Will the overlay event also fire?

Comment: A day later down-under... I tested a borderless, transparent, z-index:22 div and it triggers the mouse event; rolls our the prev/next tab. And yes, ideally I am still able to fire the - what are now underlays. But.. while I have now prev/next zone function I lose that area for divs under. I have also been considering a small expansion-indicator side bar which rolls out the prev/next tab. Either way it seem the tab will cost real estate :) Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Arfa - No problem, have some Milo and Tim Tams for me ;) I'm not sure I completely understand...is there an online example you could point to? In general though, hovering over a trigger zone would only trigger one function, not multiple, so maybe restructuring the page as you suggested would be the way forward.

Comment: Tim Tams..! that should fix the problem. Otherwise, I figure one zone, one action. I will dig about a bit more but am fairly resigned to the expansion indicator. If you have time - an aside... how do I get the @Alvin (or equiv) at the start of a comment? Cheers.

Comment: @Arfa - yeah, one zone, one action sound good (KISS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Sure, to get the [at]name, you just type the '@' symbol and the first letter of the name and after a second or so a list will appear with options. It only works when the user wouldn't normally receive a notification (so you can't do it in comments of my answer, but you can do it in comments of your question) Here's a little more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work